# Rails routing with only users username and users post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would do you set up routing / urls in Rails to have something like:

`https://mydomain.io/my-username/post/324123123123`

Where my-username is the users name. I have gotten to this point..

`https://mydomain.io/users/@my-username/post/324123123123`

and overwrote `to_param` in User model..

```
def to_param
  "@#{username}"
end
```

But how do you get rid all together of the `users` portion of the URL while still targeting Users controller etc?

Using Devise

```
devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
  end
```

Comment: are you using Devise or something you wrote yourself?  Can you post routes file?

Comment: updated to include the routes

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/) which can help you with this.